# SQUARE cannot be resolved to a variable in Processing/Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I have a problem with the following code:

```
parent.strokeCap(SQUARE);
```

I tried importing these:

```
import processing.core.PApplet; 
import processing.core.PGraphics;
import processing.core.PShape;

import processing.core.PConstants; 
import processing.core.PShapeSVG; 
import processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D;
import processing.core.PStyle;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
```

But the problem persists. Do I have to make another import? I tried to find what value SQUARE represents but was unable to find any info about what it should contain.

Comment: Maybe Processing was adding this automatically, but in order for this to compile in any IDE you should have `import static processing.core.PConstants.*;`

Comment: One of you might want to post that as an answer, so people know to skip this question.

Answer (score 0):

note that you're not writing "Processing", you're writing Java, with all the regular Java formalisms and requirements, with some of your imports simply being the Processing API library. If you need a library constant, PConstants.SQUARE will get you there.